# center a title of menu wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application that contains a menu. I need to center the title of the menu:

```
 <MenuItem Header="_Paramètres" Height="60" Width="188" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"  >
     <MenuItem Header="_Régler" Height="30" Width="188" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" Click="regler_Click_1"  x:Name="regler" Background="#FF150202" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
 </MenuItem>
```

The menu items are centered but the menu title is not.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set additionally the `HorizontalAlignment` of the root `MenuItem`. Like this.

```
<MenuItem Header="_Paramètres" Height="60" Width="188" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" 
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
    <MenuItem Header="_Régler" Height="30" Width="188" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" 
              Click="regler_Click_1"  x:Name="regler" Background="#FF150202"/>
</MenuItem>
```

Setting the `HorizontalAlignment` of the sub `MenuItems` should not be necessary with this code.

You can find some additional information about [HorizontalAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.horizontalalignment.aspx) and [HorizontalContentAlignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment.aspx) in the links.

**Edit**

Ah ok (Q&A in the comments), then the following could probably help.

```
<MenuItem Header="_Paramètres" Height="60" Width="188" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" >
    <MenuItem Header="_Régler" Height="30" Width="188" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" 
              Click="regler_Click_1"  x:Name="regler" Background="#FF150202"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
</MenuItem>
```

Btw you should create a `Style`, so that you can reuse the settings.

**Edit 2**

Last idea. If this isn't working, I'll never implement an UI with XAML again. ;o)

```
<!-- Declare this as resource -->
<Style x:Key="CenteredTextMenuItem" x:TargetType="MenuItem">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text={Binding} HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="188"/>
</Style>
```

Usage

```
<MenuItem Header="_Paramètres" Height="60" Style="{StaticResource CenteredTextMenuItem}" >
    <MenuItem x:Name="regler" Header="_Régler" Click="regler_Click_1"  
              Background="#FF150202" Style="{StaticResource CenteredTextMenuItem}"/>
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: Hmm odd. One question with *menu title* you mean the text or the whole control? Sorry, I should have asked that at the beginning.